# Navigation controller and ViewDeck library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a problem with the view deck library and the navigation controller, the app crashes when I press the back button with a popviewcontroller.
Is there someone who has added the view deck with a navigation controller present in their app?

I've inizializes the deckView in this way:

```
LeftViewController *leftViewController = [[LeftViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LeftViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];


CentraController *centralViewController = [[CentraController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CentraController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];


self.deckController = [[IIViewDeckController alloc]initWithCenterViewController:centralViewController leftViewController:leftViewController];

self.deckController.leftLedge = 100;
self.deckController.navigationControllerBehavior = IIViewDeckNavigationControllerContained;

[self.navigationController initWithRootViewController:deckController];
[window setRootViewController:self.navigationController];
```

Comment: Show some code about what u have done..it would be help us to help you..

Answer (score 4):

Use the [source](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck/blob/master/ViewDeckExample/AppDelegate.m) luke:

```
ViewController *centerController = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
self.centerController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:centerController];

IIViewDeckController* deckController =  [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:self.centerController leftViewController:self.leftController rightViewController:rightController];
```